# A room of Liars and Truth-Tellers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, puzzle

Imagine that there are $N$ people in a room.

Each person is either a Liar (always lies) or a Truth-Teller (always tells the truth).
Additionally, each person in the room knows whether someone else in the room is a Liar or Truth-Teller.

How many questions should be asked to them (individually) to determine the number of liars in the room?

---

Clearly, one should "ask the right questions" in order to minimize the number of questions asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask $O(log_2 N)$ questions of one individual.

Pick a random person and ask the person an obviously true question, e.g. "Is 1 = 1?". The person's answer determines if the person is a Liar or a Truth teller. Now proceed to ask the person the questions asked in a [Binary Search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Negate the person's answer if the person is a Liar.

Comment: That was a clever solution! Thank you for the effort. I'm ready to write a script with your implementation. Cheers!

Comment: You can avoid the throwaway question at the beginning by embedding all the questions in a modality that cancels the liar-ness. That is, for each question X you ask the individual "If I were to ask you X would you say YES?". The answer to this is YES iff X is true, regardless of whether the individual is a liar or not.

Comment: So it’s $ceiling(log_2(N+1))$ questions